# Do US/Iran dual citizens have a problem re-entering US?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, dual-nationality, iran, iranian-citizens

My husband was born in Iran. He is a naturalized US citizen and travels on his US passport. We are shortly to travel for tourism, returning through Turkey.  He holds an Iranian passport as well, which is only used when he goes to Iran to visit family, which he hopes to do in a few months. He uses that on the second leg of his flight when going there.

Have there been any problems with US citizens born in and/or traveling from one of the targeted countries being allowed re-entry into the US?